# Storyboard - How to custom UITabbarItem with UITabbarController inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem about custom UITabBarItem

First of all, you can [download my code demo](http://www.mediafire.com/?yaiz95ati4ji98r)

Now, I'm custom UITabbarcontroller at MyAppDelegate is:

```
-(void)configureiPhoneTabBar
{
    tabViewController  = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *controller1 = [[tabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self configureTabBarItemWithImageName:@"home_ON.png" : @"home.png" andText:@"Home" forViewController:controller1];

    UIViewController *controller2 = [[tabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    [self configureTabBarItemWithImageName:@"tvChannel_ON.png" : @"tvChannel.png" andText:@"TV" forViewController:controller2];
}

-(void)configureTabBarItemWithImageName:(NSString*)imageName1 : (NSString*)imageName2 andText:(NSString *)itemText forViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIImage* icon1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName1];
    UIImage* icon2 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName2];

    UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:itemText image:icon1 tag:0];
    [item1 setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:icon1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:icon2];
    [viewController setTabBarItem:item1];
}
```

I'm using a UITabbarcontroller inside UINavigationController, and I can't custom uitabaritem from appdelegate, if you run code and check "initial" in UITabBarController, interface show true, but when check at "initial" in UINavigationController is very difficult to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code to customize the tab bar to the LoginViewController (which is the one that segues to the tab bar controller). I added this code to the end of that file:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"idenLogin"]) {
        UITabBarController *tabViewController  = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIViewController *controller1 = [[tabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self configureTabBarItemWithImageName:@"home_ON.png" : @"home.png" andText:@"Home" forViewController:controller1];
        UIViewController *controller2 = [[tabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
        [self configureTabBarItemWithImageName:@"tvChannel_ON.png" : @"tvChannel.png" andText:@"TV" forViewController:controller2];
    }
}


-(void)configureTabBarItemWithImageName:(NSString*)imageName1 : (NSString*)imageName2 andText:(NSString *)itemText forViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UIImage* icon1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName1];
    UIImage* icon2 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName2];

    UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:itemText image:icon1 tag:0];
    [item1 setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:icon1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:icon2];
    [viewController setTabBarItem:item1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start your app from the login view controller, you could configure the tabBarController from that initial viewController. You can do this in a `prepareForSegue`, as there you will have a pointer to the tabBarController in `segue.destinationViewController`...

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        [self configureiPhoneTabBar:segue.destinationViewController];
    }
```

Move your tabBarViewController-configuring code into this viewController...

```
 -(void)configureiPhoneTabBar:(UITabBarController*)tabViewController
 {
        // tabViewController  = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *controller1 = [[tabViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        //...etc...
```

or send `configureiPhoneTabBar:` to your app delegate to do the configuring (but really it is best to keep code out of your app delegate).

Better still you could subclass UITabBarViewController and put your configuration code in there, triggered by viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureiPhoneTabBar];
}


-(void)configureiPhoneTabBar
  {
    UIViewController *controller1 = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        ...etc...
```

As another option, you could locate the config code in the respective viewControllers that are loaded into the tab bar.

Comment: i moving function confiureIphoneTabBar from appdelegate to a UIViewcontroller and call it, but still doesn't change tabbaritem :)

Comment: Try to get it working inside your login view controller. You just need to move your two methods there, add the prepareforsegue, and comment out the first line of configureiPhoneTabBar (my first example solution). start the app from the login screen's nav controller. this does work, I have run it on your project. If it is not working for you, put some log statements in, step through it in the debugger, and maybe start a new question if you get stuck.